# Diagram program for starting project for android?

Tags: android

I am starting a project with a team(10 activity + 7-8 fragments). But we need to create a diagram before start so everyone can focus their part without any questionmark in their head.

I found few apps and online tools like flowgorithm or draw.io. But they dont fit what i want.

Is there a customized diagram program for the android or closest?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fhRs.png)

Comment: Are you talking about Splash or some other activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use anyone of them to draw a flow chart of your app:

> 1-Microsoft Visio
>
> 2-LucidChart
>
> 3-SmartDraw
>
> 4-EdrawMax
>
> 5-Creately
>
> 6-MyDraw

if you are mac user you can use

> 1-Sketch
>
> 2-Edraw
>
> 3-LucidChart
>
> 4-Gravity
>
> 5-MyDraw

these are all use to draw a flow charts of our app and have lot more facilities.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. We chose LucidChart because it had detailed options. This list really helped us ;)